# Forward specific network traffic to other server

Tags: vpn, nat, port-forwarding

Is it possible to redirect incoming traffic on a specific port of my Ubuntu Linux server machine to another server (that has another public IP address and is located at another site)? I'm running a gameserver on the other server but I want people to be able to connect to the old IP address. Could this be done with some kind of NAT/PAT combined with VPN, perhaps?

This is my testing results with the iptables rules...

```
root@oldserver:~# tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 83
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
17:47:40.349492 IP client.63633 > oldserver.83: Flags [S], seq 783927589, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
17:47:40.597801 IP client.63634 > oldserver.83: Flags [S], seq 924277477, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
17:47:43.349118 IP client.63633 > oldserver.83: Flags [S], seq 783927589, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
17:47:43.596024 IP client.63634 > oldserver.83: Flags [S], seq 924277477, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
17:47:49.349400 IP client.63633 > oldserver.83: Flags [S], seq 783927589, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
17:47:49.600172 IP client.63634 > oldserver.83: Flags [S], seq 924277477, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <yourgameserverport> -j DNAT --to <yournewserver>:<yournewport>`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d <yournewserver> --dport <yournewport> -j MASQUERADE`

should

- redirect the traffic to the new server (no need for a VPN if it is public traffic anyway)
- disguise the redirected packets as originating from your "old" server so it surely would be in the routing path to reverse-map the response packets of the forwarded connecions.

See the respective [man page sections of `iptables`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) for details on the DNAT and MASQUERADE targets.

Note that this kind of redirection is simple to set up but would break your IP logging at the destination server - every forwarded connection would show up as originating from `<youroldserver>`. As long as this is just a transition solution, it should work out. If you want to do it permanently, you might look into tunneling the forwarded requests through a virtual interface (e.g. a VPN) and ensuring that your forwarding host `<youroldserver>` is in the response packet's routing path by routing the responses back out through the same virtual interface [using alternate routing tables](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html).

Ah, and you would need to enable routing by issuing `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` (for a temporary change) or editing /etc/sysctl.cfg and setting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` (effective after reboot).

Comment: The first command says iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Comment: The commands worked, but it doesn't work to make a connection to the port on the first server.

Comment: This reminds me: does your game server use TCP at all? If it is using UDP, re-run the commands with the `-p udp` in order to make sure UDP packets are forwarded as well. In case it still does not work, please run `tcpdump port <yourgameserverport>` on `<youroldserver>` when trying connection setup and post the results to your question.

Comment: I tested with TCP traffic to a web server first:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 83 -j DNAT --to newserver:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 80 --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE

See my tcpdump above.

Comment: your MASQUERADE rule line is wrong and thus probably not matching the packets. it should be `-d **newserver** --dport 80`.